# Getting Handler Error in Response of AWS Lambda function Test

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

Created a lambda function to retrieve value from dynamodb.When I am testing the function I am getting an error in response?

[image]

[image]

Couldn't find any answer on the internet.

Comment: Name your function `lambda_handler` instead of `handler`.

Comment: Please be mindful not to share images of code or exceptions as it's against the community guidelines

Answer (score 1):

Your function should be named `lambda_handler`

```
def lambda_handler(event,context):
```

The documentation provides more information on this here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-handler.html

Answer (score 0):

Seems like in line 6 you have used

> def handler(event,context):

instead of

> def lambda_handler(event,context):

If you want to keep using def handler(event,context): you also need to enter this in 'Handler' option in 'Runtime Settings'

[image]